# Typeahead suggestions with text below each suggestion

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, handlebars.js, typeahead.js

I am working on a project where users have characters.

I am creating a search function for these characters where the user types in the characters name and can then search for matching records.

I'm using typeahead in the input box and am currently bringing back character names and their username.

I am wanting to display this in the suggestions list with the character name appearing as it normally would, and then the username below it as slightly smaller text.
Something like this:

[image: Suggestion with username on second line]

To do this I have tried the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var characters = new Bloodhound({
            remote: {
                url: '/search/characters/find?q=%QUERY%',
                wildcard: '%QUERY%'
            },
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('q'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
        });

        $("#searchinput").typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
        {
            source: characters.ttAdapter(),
            templates: {
                suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p>@{{ concatname }}</p><p><small>@{{ username }}</small></p>')
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

However this only shows the character name in the suggestion.

To test the data was coming in correctly, I tried this and it worked (character name then a hyphen and then the username):

```
suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p>@{{ concatname }} - @{{ username }}</p>')
```

An example of the data returned is below:

```
[  
   {  
      concatname:"Great Work",
      username:"manager"
   },
   {  
      concatname:"Scrim Greaves",
      username:"glees"
   }
]
```

How can I get the username to appear correctly below the character name?

Note the `@{{ }}` syntax is necessary as I use Laravel and the `@` symbol escapes the double curly brace, which is then rendered as `{{ }}`.

Comment: Have you tried it without the @? I'm not that familiar with Laravel but I wouldn't think that the Handlebars compiler would go through the Laravel interpreter.

Comment: The laravel interpreter renders these as `{{ }}` on the page and this happens when the page is rendered, which before the Handlebars compiler is even run. If I view the page source once the page loads, I only see `{{ }}`. If I don't put the @ then laravels blade engine will interpret it as a php variable and the page won't load.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice it was all inline in your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is that you don't have a wrapper around your to `<p>` elements. The template should have one element containing everything and is most likely trimming the second `<p>`.

Change your template code:

```
templates: {
  suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<div><p>@{{ concatname }}</p><p><small>@{{ username }}</small></p></div>')
}
```

Comment: You were right! It just needed the `<div>` wrapper and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following website, there is a memeber search bar and Iam using typeahead with Laravel, and also I am using it in the registration page..

[Click here](http://www.techalyst.com/)